# The RSA public key generated by C# is an XML file. How can the public key be decrypted or converted in PHP?

Tags: c#, php

The public key file generated by C# is as follows:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>1bpPEi4vfSnR+PYdaxqWkkLRbaPMcJYQqnMTg9i2uBQcBQZ0V0k8QBDPHK8wcGs4OAx2WD461fcNsB7aXCa8xPsLM4DO4M+xyfg/HmHEaTQrR1738YaK1WerA890xGeGFybkMRJNbZHLESe0mnsWdeNbyCJs8I7EeLWMHzBPuu0=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

How to convert or decrypt in PHP?

Comment: What algorithm is used to generate this key?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: @Urmat Zhenaliev: its a RSA public key

Comment: The phpseclib-library (v3) is been able to load a  xml styled public key and verify or encrypt a message.

Comment: @MichaelFehr - phpseclib v1 and v2 are able to do that as well lol

Answer (score 1):

Using phpseclib v2,

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>1bpPEi4vfSnR+PYdaxqWkkLRbaPMcJYQqnMTg9i2uBQcBQZ0V0k8QBDPHK8wcGs4OAx2WD461fcNsB7aXCa8xPsLM4DO4M+xyfg/HmHEaTQrR1738YaK1WerA890xGeGFybkMRJNbZHLESe0mnsWdeNbyCJs8I7EeLWMHzBPuu0=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>');

echo $rsa;
```

Outputs the following:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVuk8SLi99KdH49h1rGpaSQtFt
o8xwlhCqcxOD2La4FBwFBnRXSTxAEM8crzBwazg4DHZYPjrV9w2wHtpcJrzE+wsz
gM7gz7HJ+D8eYcRpNCtHXvfxhorVZ6sDz3TEZ4YXJuQxEk1tkcsRJ7SaexZ141vI
ImzwjsR4tYwfME+67QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RSA public key was generated by C# and is in the (Microsoft own) XML-encoding. There are several way to convert it programatically but I show you the easiest way.

As it is a **public key** you can use an online converter for this tak, e.g. https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter.

**Never ever convert a private key with online tools.**

Just copy the complete key in the form and receive the public key in **PEM-encoding**:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVuk8SLi99KdH49h1rGpaSQtFt
o8xwlhCqcxOD2La4FBwFBnRXSTxAEM8crzBwazg4DHZYPjrV9w2wHtpcJrzE+wsz
gM7gz7HJ+D8eYcRpNCtHXvfxhorVZ6sDz3TEZ4YXJuQxEk1tkcsRJ7SaexZ141vI
ImzwjsR4tYwfME+67QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This key can be used in PHP for OpenSSL RSA public key encryption by using "openssl_public_encrypt" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php)-

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the result is not what I want